Reproducibility fof PyTorch for nn.Conv2d
While training a model using the MMDetection 3.x framework, I've encountered an issue where the results of the nn.Conv2d layer in the ResNet backbone of Faster R-CNN vary for the same input during each debugging session. I ran the model on the same environment.

As seen in the image above, the RCNN returns slightly different rpn results every debug on the same input.
@MODELS.register_module()
class ResNet(BaseModule):
    """ResNet backbone.
...

def forward(self, x):
        """Forward function."""
        if self.deep_stem:
            x = self.stem(x)
        else:
            x = self.conv1(x)
            x = self.norm1(x)
            x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.maxpool(x)
        outs = []
        for i, layer_name in enumerate(self.res_layers):
            res_layer = getattr(self, layer_name)
            x = res_layer(x)
            if i in self.out_indices:
                outs.append(x)
        return tuple(outs)

self.conv1(x) is nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(2, 2), padding=(3, 3), bias=False), and it produces different results every debug, even though x and self.conv1.weight are still identital.
I have tried most common solutions such as setting the seed using def set_random_seed(), ensuring consistent PyTorch/CUDA versions, initializing weights identically, setting deterministic=True and benchmark=False, among others, but the problem persists. The use of use_deterministic_algorithms(True) was also attempted, which should theoretically resolve the non-deterministic behavior of nn.Conv2d, but it hasn't worked in this case.
`
def set_random_seed(seed, deterministic=False):
"""Set random seed.
Args:
    seed (int): Seed to be used.
    deterministic (bool): Whether to set the deterministic option for
        CUDNN backend, i.e., set `torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic`
        to True and `torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark` to False.
        Default: False.
"""
random.seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)
torch.manual_seed(seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)
if deterministic:
    torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
    torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False`

Interestingly, this issue does not occur immediately. Initially, the results are consistent, but starting from around the 10th input, the outputs of the conv1 layer differ for identical inputs in each debugging session. I have confirmed that both the input tensor and conv1.weight are the same before applying conv1 each time. Despite this, the results diverge from the 10th input onwards. Has anyone experienced a similar issue or has insights on this problem?

Have you called .eval() on the model?
